# Webpack - React ES6 transpile every template (src to dist)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack for react(es6) project.

### My problem

I have built **react app with ES6**, so everywhere i have used **import** keyword for dependency. Now for server side rendering i am using NodeJS so its not support **import** yet. For this i have to use ***require*** instead of ***import***.

Now i have used webpack for bundling my app, but it always generate final bundle file (single.bundle.js), That's why i am not able to import chunk of transpiled code for server side rendering.

### Solution

If it is possible to transpile every file **(src to dist)**, then i can import this es5 file into nodejs server code.

### Question

Is this possible with webpack to transpile whole folder with same out put rather than bundle file ?

Otherwise i have to use grunt or gulp. :(

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed your `package.json`

Comment: @Ursus package.json or webpack.config.js

Comment: Let's see both please

Comment: @Ursus https://gist.github.com/Nishchit14/ba6edd1b36bb5161206847acf49072b3

Comment: @Ursus https://gist.github.com/Nishchit14/82916291809827e2b6113e934adcffed

Comment: Sorry can't see anything wrong with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116790/discussion-between-nishchit-dhanani-and-u-r-s-u-s).

Answer (score 2):

You can use webpack for server too. It will transpile to webpack server bundle only your specific code containing react and excluding node_modules by **externals** option. Here is example of `webpack.config.js` for **server side**

```
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function(x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function(mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/server.js', 
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        console: false,
        global: false,
        process: false,
        Buffer: false,
        __filename: false,
        __dirname: false,
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
}
```